# How can i bring the image in my xhtml page?

Tags: java, maven

I have a Maven project. I can upload image in my database, but i want to bring this image in my xhtml page.

My Java Code;

```
private StreamedContent secilenMusteriResimi;

public StreamedContent getSecilenMusteriResimi()
    {
        return secilenMusteriResimi;
    }

    public void setSecilenMusteriResimi(StreamedContent secilenMusteriResimi)
    {
        this.secilenMusteriResimi = secilenMusteriResimi;
    }

public void showImage()
{

    RequestContext.getCurrentInstance().update("panel");
    imagesPath = selectedImages.getPath();
    try

    {

        InputStream inputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(selectedImages.getProfilresmi());
        BufferedImage resimData = ImageIO.read(inputStream);
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        ImageIO.write(resimData, "jpg", os);
        secilenMusteriResimi = new DefaultStreamedContent(new ByteArrayInputStream(os.toByteArray()), "image/jpg");

        //  secilenMusteriResimi = new DefaultStreamedContent(inputStream);

    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

My xhtml Code;

```
<h:form>
            <p:dataTable id="table" var="img"
                value="#{musteriBean.musteriTanimlariListesi}"
                style="width: 500px;" selectionMode="single"
                selection="#{musteriBean.selectedImages}" rowKey="#{img.id}">
                <p:ajax event="rowSelect" listener="#{musteriBean.showImage()}" update=":panel" />
                <p:column headerText="ID">
                    <h:outputText value="#{img.id}" />
                </p:column>
            </p:dataTable>
        </h:form>
        <br />
        <h:form id="panel">
            <p:panelGrid  columns="1">
                <p:graphicImage value="#{musteriBean.secilenMusteriResimi}"/>
            </p:panelGrid>
        </h:form>
```

When i run the program;

http: //hizliresim.com/Y3lky6

How can i fix this problem? I am waiting for your help. Thank you.

Comment: What problem? You haven't told us what the problem is.

Comment: I said it. I want to bring image in my xhtml page. Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You cant just embedd image in html like you are doing.
In html code you have to point only url for image and let the browser download the image.
The image url should looks like:

```
http: //hizliresim.com/Y3lky6/readMyImage/1234
```

or

```
http: //hizliresim.com/Y3lky6/readMyImage?imageId=1234
```

Then you have to create servlet 'readMyImage' reading from database image with given id and serving it to the browser.